# Does mapreduce from the Qt library preserve the sequence of the input files?

Tags: c++, qt, mapreduce

```
    WordCount countWords(const QString &file)
    {
        QFile f(file);
        f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        QTextStream textStream(&f);
        WordCount wordCount;

        while (textStream.atEnd() == false)
            foreach (QString word, textStream.readLine().split(" "))
                wordCount[word] += 1;

        return wordCount;
    }

...

QStringList files = findFiles("../../", QStringList() << "*.cpp" << "*.h");

...

int mapReduceTime = 0;
{
    QTime time;
    time.start();
    WordCount total = mappedReduced(files, countWords, reduce);
    mapReduceTime = time.elapsed();
    qDebug() << "MapReduce" << mapReduceTime;
}
```

Say I want to keep track of which file I am dealing with, can I just create a global static variable, and increment it each time it starts running, inside of the countWord function to know that I am doing some processing on file number 1? Or is it impossible to know which files is going to be processed first? I am asking because mapreduce allows parallel processing, but I don't know how the OS is going to schedule the threads.

Comment: You really need to post complete code for what you're trying to do, and say how it fails at achieving what you wish to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to know precisely what order will the processing run in, since each mapping operation will usually take a different time.

A simple solution is to process not the raw file list, but a list of (index, filename) pairs.

You should also skip the empty strings, and at least handle the failure to open a given file for reading. The idiomatic way of writing `boolExpr == false` is simply `! boolExpr`.

```
typedef QPair<int, QString> FileEntry;

WordCount countWords(const FileEntry &entry)
{
    WordCount wordCount;
    QFile f(entry.second);
    if (!f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) return wordCount;
    QTextStream ts(&f);

    while (!ts())
      foreach (QString word, ts().split(" ", QString::SkipEmptyParts))
        wordCount[word] ++;

    return wordCount;
}

QStringList f = findFiles("../../", QStringList() << "*.cpp" << "*.h");
QList<FileEntry> fileEntries;
fileEntries.reserve(f.size());
int i = 0;
foreach (QString file, f)
  fileEntries << qMakePair(i++, file); 
mappedReduced(fileEntries, countWords, reduce);
```

Comment: let's say you have a 2d array, and you pass each row to mapreduce

Comment: ah ok, I didn't see the edit. why would you use tuple instead of QPair though?

Comment: for putting everything back together how would you do it?

Comment: @user3435009 The tuple is simply an extension of pair to any number of items. A pair carries exactly and only two items.

Comment: @user3435009 Putting *what* together? You mean how to write the `reduce` function?

Comment: yeah, how would you write it and keep the initial order?

Comment: @user345009 The reduce function collapses multiple results into one, so the notion of order vanishes. What order are you talking about? Seriously, just write complete code for what you wish to do, and say how it behaves that doesn't agree with your intentions/spec.

Comment: yeah I know but let's say you want to reduce it in the a certain order even though it's useless.